# How to toggle a class on li after click event in angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have an unorder list like below. I want to remove the `active` and `arrow-down` classes from previously activated li element (in case when I click on any other `li` element) and want to add arrow-up class to it. Furthermore I want to add `active` and `arrow-down` classes to the recently clicked `li` element. In the following code `link 1` is activated by default.

```
<ul class="sibe-bar-menu">
    <li class="active arrow-down"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to acheive a code like below once after clicking the 3rd `li` element.

```
<ul class="sibe-bar-menu">
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="active arrow-down"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="arrow-up"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngClass` for this, in conjunction with `clicked`.

In the HTML, add a `click` function to each of them, to select it. Also add an `ngClass` to show the relevant classes if it is the selected one.

```
<ul class="sibe-bar-menu">
    <li [ngClass]="clicked === 0 ? 'active arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'" (click)="select(0)"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="clicked === 1 ? 'active arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'" (click)="select(1)"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="clicked === 2 ? 'active arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'" (click)="select(2)"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="clicked === 3 ? 'active arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'" (click)="select(3)"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Finally, in the backend, create the `select` function

```
clicked = 0;

select(i) {
  this.clicked = i;
}
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxappb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Can we not select multiple li?